# error was returned when trying to run names(x) in R studio?

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R and i have little knowledge in programming. Please help me to solve this question if you can.

when i try to run the function "names(x)" in RGui, it is alright. It returned the names attributes i have entered or it will return "NULL".

However, when i try to do the same thing in Rstudio, it returned

> > x<-vector()
> >
> > names(x)
>
> Error in names(x) : invalid 'mode' argument

How should i solve it? Thank you.

Comment: It didn't give me any error in my Rstudio. Either reopen Rstudio or reinstall it

Comment: thanks! i clean up objects from my environment and no more error is pop-up again.

Answer (score 0):

```
help (names)
```

In Notes you can see:

```
For vectors, the names are one of the attributes 
with restrictions on the possible values.
```

I suppose, you should set attributes to get it's names.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know i can see the names under attributes but names() is a more convenient function for me. anyway, i solve the problem finally. Thanks.